# Simple riddle involving time travel

Tags: riddle

This is a simple one, but it's BTTF (Back to the Future) day, so I figured it was appropriate:

> What goes a minute in four seconds?

Comment: A really bad clock? Four regular clocks? :P

Comment: Technical: <blahblah>relativity< /blahblah>  Something to do with time dilation, time-travel, and relative velocities.

Comment: The TARDIS?  The Doctor?

Comment: Something travelling at ~900 knots.

Comment: "simple" and "time travel" are not known for going together well.

Comment: Everything travels through time, just some things move faster than others.

Comment: @Deusovi how does 4 regular clocks go a minute in 4 seconds?

Comment: @LocustHorde: It was originally "a minute in 15 seconds".

Comment: https://xkcd.com/209/ "So the boat travels through time?" "Sure, just like everything else. It also goes over water!"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The

> Earth rotates through one minute of arc every 4 seconds.

Comment: Got it.  I figured it'd be a pretty simple one, but it was fun to think about.

Comment: Hmm... The title was somewhat misleading then. Where's the time-travel?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK : That was intentional misdirection.  However, the other answer I was intending and would have accepted was the Sun, which travels across the sky over a period of time.  So: time, travel.  Just not exactly time travel.

Comment: "Simple riddle involving time/travel" would perhaps be more accurate, but also a bit of a giveaway.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: well.. one travels four second ahead in time in that four second time lapse. Nothing fancy, one sec per sec speed, but it is time traveling :-) But you are correct. Too.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - By the way I liked the riddle and upvoted it. I just don't personally think misdirection is a good idea. I tried it myself on one of my first few questions and it just caused annoyance.  I believe that, with a little extra thought, it is possible to make the title and clues accurate but not obvious.

Answer (score 14):

> The hour hand on a 24-hour clock.
> There are 360 degrees in a circle and 60 minutes in a degree, so a minute is 1/360/60 = 1/21600 of a circle.  The hour hand moves 1/24/60/60 = 1/86400 of a circle each second, so in 4 seconds it moves 4/86400 = 1/21600.
> Note:  If you say "earth", make sure to qualify that you are talking about its rotation with respect to the sun, since its rotation with respect to the stars is about 1/365 off of one full rotation each day.

Comment: +1: Can't deny that this would also be correct, though not the intended answer.  (I was thinking of the sun's position in the sky, which takes the relative rotation into account, but was planning to accept "earth" as well, since it depends on your point of reference.)

Comment: Your equation isn't balanced, just a typo you might want to fix. 4/21600 != 1/21600. :)

Answer (score 8):

There is no time travel involved.

> The fastest cars in the world (not counting drag racers)

Because... (The math is pretty rough but I think it shows I'm on the right track)

> "Minute" means "minute of arc" and not a unit of time
>  [Diameter of Earth](https://www.google.com/search?q=Diameter%20of%20Earth) = 7,917.5 miles
>  Perimeter of Earth = 24,873.6 miles (I know it's not really a sphere)
>  One degree of arc = 69.1 miles
>  One minute of arc = 1.15 miles
>  [Top speed of the Venom GT](https://www.google.com/search?q=venom%20gt%20top%20speed) = 270 mph
>  Distance traveled by Venom GT in 15 seconds = 1.13 miles

Comment: Ahhhhh! OP edited as I was answering. I was on the right track, though, for the original time of 15 seconds.

Comment: Sorry about that.  My original mistake was based on a rewording of the puzzle: "What goes fifteen minutes in a minute?"  Which is the same thing, just multiplied.

Comment: @EngineerToast, StackExchange sites: where you post as quickly as possible regardless of quality before ninja editing a correct answer (for the timestamp!)

Comment: If you only care about longitude, any vehicle traveling slowly around the south pole could accomplish the same thing :)

Comment: @acbabis Fair point, since the minute of arc here is in reference to the Earth's rotation.